# Drawing a colored box around the entire frame in beamer

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox

I am trying to make a slide show in beamer where every slide/frame has a colored box around the edge of the frame. I have done this before using a template slide (.png), but I was wondering if there was a way to do this with a tcolorbox or something.[image: outlined_slide]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use tikz:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
  \draw[blue,dash=on 20pt off 10pt phase 0pt,line width=0.3cm] (current page.south west) rectangle (current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: youre the best, thanks!

Comment: @JaimeArturoGomez You're welcome!